# Passing a javascript variable to PHP to use with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php

I know, I know, one is client side and one is server side. I had to use PHP to grab a few arrays of data and I'm passing this data in to Google Charts geomaps. E.g:

```
echo 'var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ["Country", "Popularity"],
      ';
      foreach($countries as $key=>$val){
           echo '["'.$key.'",'.$val.'],';
      }
echo ']);
```

When a user clicks on one of the countries (using an event listener) on the map it puts this value into a variable:

```
var country = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
```

Now I need to pass this to the PHP array, so I can do something like:

```
if($country == country){
//do whatever
}
```

Comment: You need to have `<script></script>` tags when using JavaScript, however I doubt that will fix it.

Comment: use ajax call to send data to php file and you can return some data as well if you want

Comment: First of all: you need to learn to distinguish between JS running within your browser and PHP running on your webserver. Then you will see, that there's no way of "passing a variable from JS to PHP" in one source like `$country == country`. Instead, make yourself familiar with AJAX and JSON. Google for these terms and find that intro suitable for you.

Comment: What is *'do whatever'* is important. If it's just a few calculations and other basic stuff, code it in javscript. If it's a db-query, you have to send an ajax request, as others mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a Javascript value to PHP you'd need to use AJAX. With jQuery, it would look something like this (most basic example possible):

```
 var country = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
 $.post('file.php', {country: country});
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but I can't quite get it to work. When I send the country over, and save to $_SESSION, it can only be recalled back on page refresh. I can't really use function(data) for it either because that's a JS variable...